# Is C++ std::atomic compatible with pthreads?

Tags: c++, linux, concurrency, pthreads, atomic

I have 2 `pthread` threads where one is writing a bool value and another is reading it.
I dont care for portability. Its x86 architecture. The only which concerns me is writing thread sets bool to true and starts doing its own work (which happens once a day at midnight)  closing a file. And the other thread had read the bool as false and proceeds with its work (writing to a file) at the same time. Its very difficult to reproduce this scenario so I better get best possible theoretical solution.

Can I use std::atomic in case of pthreads?

Comment: Why pthreads? Why are you not using `std::thread`? I am not expert in C++, but if `std::thread` is available to you, then it probably is a bad idea (like, maybe even UB) to use any other means to create new threads.

Comment: It seems you are trying to use a `std::atomic_bool` as if it was a `std::mutex`. You better have to use `std::mutex` instead. But to answer your question, `std::atomic` is made to be used with threads otherwise it has little meaning to use it, so yes.

Comment: std::condition_variable could also be useful, but I agree with the observation that the atomic bool is probably misused. Of course, if you set a bool to true (assuming it was false) and **at the same time** read that bool, then it's a 50/50 flip what result the second thread will see. Atomic just means that you get true or false, but not purple or 42.

Comment: @MSalters, that comment could be misleading to a beginner. "Atomic" does _not_ mean that the reader will only see legal values of the declared type. It means that the reader will only ever see either the initial value, or a value that was subsequently stored by the program. In the case of atomic _boolean_ variables, it just so happens that the program doesn't have to store very many legal values before every legal value becomes a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use std::atomic in case of pthreads?

Yes, that's what `std::atomic` *is for*.

It works with `std::thread`, POSIX threads, and *any* other kind of threads. Behind the scenes it uses "magical" compiler annotations to prevent certain thread-incompatible optimizations, and processor-specific locking instructions to guarantee that thread-safe code is generated<sup>1</sup>.

It makes (almost) no sense to use `std::atomic` *without* threads (you could use `std::atomic` instead of `volatile` for signal handlers, but there is no advantage in doing so).

> The only which concerns me ...

The rest of your question makes no sense to me.

---

<sup>1</sup> When used *correctly*, which is often non-trivial thing to do, and which is why you *generally* should try *not* to use `std::atomic` unless you are an expert.

Comment: Pedantically, `std::atomic` can also be used instead of `volatile` for variables shared with signal handlers.

Comment: It could be used for signals, but _shouldn't be_.

Comment: It _can_, not _could_. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: the question clearly states - threads. why do you say `It makes no sense to use without threads.`?

Comment: The question is about **pthreads**, not about threads in general.

Comment: ok then just say - no it cant be used with pthreads.

Comment: @BoppityBop I don't think you understood the answer. It's definitely _yes_.

Comment: @BoppityBop there is just one kind of threads: system. Call them `pthreads`, `std::threads`—doesn't matter. `std::atomic` is about atomicity and serialization, it doesn't care about what you call your threads either (Standard wording cares, obviously, but implementation wouldn't).

Comment: @ixSci, although it is *commonly* true that pthreads, on a system that has them, is an interface to native system threads and that `std::thread` is also an interface to native system threads, possibly as a wrapper for pthreads, such configurations are by no means the only ones possible.  Nor can threading implementations that are not pthreads and do not provide (multiple) native system threads be ruled out.